# What is the size of the HiRISE footprints?

Tags: mars, hirise

On the [HiRISE map](https://www.uahirise.org/hiwish/browse), you can display the footprints of prior observations. What is the size in kilometers of these footprints?

Answer (score 8):

HiRISE uses "pushbroom" imaging so the length of the footprint is variable depending on the length of "Time Delay and Integration" (TDI) used in a given observation.

However, [the latest MRO HiRISE instrument SPICE kernel (ik) from NAIF (v12)](https://naif.jpl.nasa.gov/pub/naif/pds/data/mro-m-spice-6-v1.0/mrosp_1000/data/ik/mro_hirise_v12.ti) suggests:

> At the nominal 300 km MRO orbital altitude the instrument can acquire image swaths of approximately 6 kilometers cross-orbit and 20 kilometers along-orbit.